# styling the attribute img

Tags: css, custom-data-attribute

Can I style JUST the img in the data attribute data-vc-parallax-image? if I use this it fades the

as well as the img bg. As this doesn't create an img tag.

```
[data-vc-parallax-image="../wp-content/uploads/-Woman-Cleaning-The-Floor-With--1.jpg"]{
opacity:0.4; }

<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" data-vc-
parallax="1.5" data-vc-parallax-o-fade="on" data-vc-parallax-image="../wp-
content/uploads/-Woman-Cleaning-The-Floor-With--1.jpg">
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot (as far as I know).

As I see, you are using WordPress with Visual Composer plugin. You can style that image in Photoshop (for example) and upload it with the desired opacity (transparency). Saved as a png of course.

Comment: thanks, that was my next try after inserting the image as div::after {url(bg.jpg) etc}

Comment: you can use pseudo elements , yes. But in your case you will loose the parallax effect . So i suggest you use a transparent background image